# Yii2, Queue, RabbitMQ (amqp_interop). Не исполняются задания

Tags: yii2, centos, очередь, rabbitmq

Совсем не гуру в настройке очередей и не только их. Вообще с *nix системами сталкиваюсь к своему стыду крайне редко. Диагностика проблем вызывает много затруднений.

Настраиваю очереди в проекте на YII2.
ОС: CentOS
Версия RabbitMQ 3.9.12

конфигурация в yii

```
$rabbit = [
    'class' => \yii\queue\amqp_interop\Queue::class,
    'driver' => yii\queue\amqp_interop\Queue::ENQUEUE_AMQP_LIB,
    'host' => '127.0.0.1',
    'port' => 5672,
    'user' => '***',
    'password' => '***',
    'as log' => \yii\queue\LogBehavior::class,
];
...
'components' => [
        'queue' => array_merge($rabbit, [
            'queueName' => 'queue_pro',
            'exchangeName' => 'exchange_pro',
        ]),
```

ставлю сообщение в очередь классически

```
        Yii::$app->queue->push(new SendMessage([
            'method' => $method,
            'params' => $params,
        ]));
```

В web-интерфейсе RabbitMQ вижу, что задача ставится в очередь и исполняется.
В логах rabbitmq вижу следующее

```
2022-01-17 15:40:23.442624+03:00 [info] <0.14288.13> accepting AMQP connection <0.14288.13> (127.0.0.1:59516 -> 127.0.0.1:5672)
2022-01-17 15:40:23.484819+03:00 [info] <0.14288.13> connection <0.14288.13> (127.0.0.1:59516 -> 127.0.0.1:5672): user '***' authenticated and granted access to vhost '/'
2022-01-17 15:40:23.861832+03:00 [info] <0.14288.13> closing AMQP connection <0.14288.13> (127.0.0.1:59516 -> 127.0.0.1:5672, vhost: '/', user: '***')
```

в коде SendMessage (находится в @app/commands)

```
    public function execute($queue)
    {

        file_put_contents('file123.txt', PHP_EOL . 111222, FILE_APPEND);

    }
```

Не запускается задание (. В логах Yii нет ни каких даже попыток запуска скрипта (ну или я смотрю не там).

Не понимаю как диагностировать и устранить проблему.

Буду признателен за любую полезную информацию.

Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Ну собственно, как и предполагалось - слона то я и не приметил )))
Сам воркер (обработчик) то и не запустил. Читать нужно документацию, а не готовые команды для консоли использовать ...

Детально расписано здесь: https://www.yiiframework.com/extension/yiisoft/yii2-queue/doc/guide/2.0/ru/worker

Суть - положить в автозагрузку (в качестве службы) запуск команды

```
/usr/bin/php /var/www/my_project/yii queue/listen --verbose
```

Конфигурацию службы только относительно примера чуток подправил добавив порядок запуска и зависимость от сервиса RabbitMQ (иначе ошибка при запуске системы).
Получилось так:

```
[Unit]
Description=Yii Queue Worker %I
After=network.target rabbitmq-server.service
Wants=rabbitmq-server.service

[Service]
User=apache
Group=apache
ExecStart=/usr/bin/php /var/www/my_project/yii queue/listen --verbose
Restart=on-failure

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Это положил в файл
yii-queue@.service в папку /etc/systemd/system/
Дальше в консоли

```
systemctl daemon-reload // обновляем список сервисов
systemctl start yii-queue@1 yii-queue@2 // запускаем два экземпляра очередей (можно больше)
systemctl status yii-queue@1 yii-queue@2 // на всякий случай проверяем, что все хорошо
systemctl enable yii-queue@1 yii-queue@2 // кладем это все в автозагрузку
```